# how to associate two models with multiple has many associations?

Tags: elixir, ecto

For eg:
Class and Students.
A Class will have many students in a has many relationship, grouped as `has_many` attendants or `has_many` sections.
actually that sections thing is semantically useless. I want to know if a multiple has many association between two models is possible?

```
# Class
class has_many :attendants, Students, foreign_key: :student_id
class has_many :sections, Students, foreign_key: :student_section

# Student
student belongs_to :class, Class, foreign_key: :student_id
student belongs_to :class, Class, foreign_key: :student_section
```

Something like that?

Comment: It would be very easy to try something like this. Is there some reason you haven't?

Comment: @JustinWood I am getting different kinds of errors. like schema already set or foreign_key cannot be same as name

Comment: The "schema already set" is because your have two relations called `:class` on student. You need to call them something different.